# no suitable constructor exists to convert from "cocos2d::CCObject *" to "std::basic_string

Tags: cocos2d-x

I try to get the std strings keys from CCDictionary allKeys() method 
but i got stack when i try to get the key from the CCArray
this is what i have :

```
CCArray* pAllkeys = CCArray::create();
pAllkeys->addObjectsFromArray(GameSingleTone::getInstance()->getGemsDictionary()->allKeys());
pAllkeys->retain();
```

here i try to get the keys but im getting compilation error:

```
int gemsToRemoveCount = pAllkeys ->count();
for(int i=0;i<gemsToRemoveCount;i++)
{

    std::string gemKey =  pAllkeys->objectAtIndex(i);
}
```

this is the compilation error im getting :
    4

```
IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "cocos2d::CCObject *" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"
```

**update**
found the solution after diggings the headers

```
CCString* name = dynamic_cast<CCString*>(pAllkeys->objectAtIndex(i));
std::string newkey = name->m_sString;
```

Comment: dynamic casting is a very costly operation, you can use either static cast or normal type casting.

Comment: i didnt found any other way ...

Comment: CCString* name = (CCString*)pAllkeys->objectAtIndex(i); (basic type casting, since you are not having null checks for name, both serve same purpose in your case)

Answer (score 0):

CCArray is a container that can contain only CCObject classes. By adding std::string objects you violated that, but this really isn't your fault - the CCArray class should have type-checked on add and failed at that point.

As it is now it reports the error because `objectAtIndex` returns a `CCObject*` but you're assuming that it contains and returns objects of type `std::string`.

Solution: use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead of CCArray to store strings.

Comment: well i want to avoid looping i want to use the retured value of the ->allKeys()  CCDictionary

Comment: LearnCocos2D check the solution in the question